# NFS mount fails, permission denied, no export entry

Tags: linux, nfs

I have a problem mounting a NFS share that I can't solve that is driving me nuts. This is the situation:

Three machines involved:
Host A: mandrake, IP 192.168.1.4, NFS server
Host B: athlon64, IP 192.168.1.64, NFS client
Host C: lap-fzs-2, IP 192.168.1.27, NFS client

Host A has an NFS server running which exports a directory that gets mounted by host B. This works flawless and has been working since ages. No problemo. Now host C comes into the picture. Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, modern system. I tried to mount the same share from host A but get a permission denied error:

```
root@lap-fzs-2:~# mount -t nfs mandrake:/data /data -onfsvers=2
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting mandrake:/data
```

The fact that it works between hosts A and B should be prove that the NFS export per se is working. Here is the info I can give that makes me think it should work. Maybe someone sees what I don't and knows why this fails on the new host C.

Server exports:

```
[root@mandrake /root]# cat /etc/exports
/suse 192.168.1.0/16(ro,no_root_squash)
/data 192.168.1.0/24(rw)
#/data3 192.168.2.0/24(rw)
#/data 192.168.2.0/16(rw,all_squash,anonuid=500,anongid=500)
#/data3 192.168.2.0/16(rw,all_squash,anonuid=500,anongid=500)

[root@mandrake /root]# exportfs
/suse           192.168.1.0/16
/data           192.168.1.0/24
```

The portmapper is running, the exports are known and mounted by host B "athlon64".

```
[root@mandrake /root]# showmount -e
Export list for mandrake:
/data 192.168.1.0/24
/suse 192.168.1.0/16
[root@mandrake /root]# showmount -a
All mount points on mandrake:
atlhon64.acme.local:/data
```

When the athlon64 host mounts the NFS share, the server log shows success:

```
Feb 11 20:06:46 mandrake mountd[460]: authenticated mount request from atlhon64.acme.local:770 for /data (/data)
```

But when the host C tries to mount the same share, the server log shows:

```
Feb 11 20:12:42 mandrake mountd[460]: refused mount request from lap-fzs-2 for /data (/): no export entry
```

Host C sees the server, reaches the portmapper and the nfsd, but fail at the permissions.

```
root@lap-fzs-2:~# showmount -e 192.168.1.4
Export list for 192.168.1.4:
/data 192.168.1.0/24
/suse 192.168.1.0/16


root@lap-fzs-2:~# mount -t nfs -v mandrake:/data /data -onfsvers=2,proto=udp
mount.nfs: timeout set for Mon Feb 11 21:49:23 2013
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nfsvers=2,proto=udp,addr=192.168.1.4'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=2, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.4 prog 100003 vers 2 prot UDP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=1, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.4 prog 100005 vers 1 prot UDP port 636
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting mandrake:/data
```

I have to use NFSv2 on the client. Using NFSv4 will fail as the server doesn't support it. It fails as it tries to connect via TCP directly to 2049 but the port isn't open. No fallback happens. Using NFSv3 will result in a RPC program/version mismatch.

What am I missing?

**Update:**
All three machines are on one LAN, on the same switch. There is no firewall active on host C:

```
root@lap-fzs-2:~# iptables -vnL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 17 packets, 1853 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 20 packets, 5611 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Nor on host A:

```
[root@mandrake /root]# ipchains -L 
Chain input (policy ACCEPT):
Chain forward (policy ACCEPT):
Chain output (policy ACCEPT):
```

Comment: Firewall on Host C (or less likely Host A) ?  (What does /sbin/iptables -vnL show ?)

Comment: Nope, no firewalls, one LAN segment.

Comment: try `exportfs -a` command at Host A, then try `mount` command on Host C.  Try explicit hostname or the full IP address in `/etc/exports`.

Comment: How would that help? The server does an `exportfs -a` at boot time and since this is not a new entry, it's already exported. The exports file didn't change, it's just a new host that should mount it and can't.

Comment: @sawdust your edit contained the right hint: using the full IP address in `/etc/exports` actually makes it work. I now have the /24 net plus the full IP listed and host C can mount. Haven't tried host B yet. Any idea why this is?  I noticed that host B (the working one) did use a version 2 MNT call, while host C resorted to a version 1 MNT call.

Comment: *"How would that help?"* -- I offered that suggestion because I always have problems accessing my NFS server even after reboots.  Explicitly issuing the `exportfs -a` is the reliable solution (for me).  No idea why a full IP address works, other than it directly confronts the *"no export entry"* error description.

Comment: Well, thanks for your help! I don't understand it, but it works now, and for now that is all I need.

Comment: @sawdust: Since you found the solution, could you add your comment as an answer so that Florian can mark this question as answered?

Comment: If it works when you specify the full IP address I'd say this is a netmask issue. What netmask do you have configured on the hosts?

Comment: The netmask is 255.255.255.0 on both machines, A and C. I haven't checked B, but would assume the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Feb 11 20:12:42 mandrake mountd[460]: refused mount request from lap-fzs-2 for /data (/): no export entry

Since the server's rejection notice claims that there is *"no export entry"* for Host C, then perhaps you should try an unambiguous line in the `/etc/exports` file with the explicit hostname or the full IP address for C.

Also try issuing an `exportfs -a` command at the server.
I often have problems accessing my NFS server even after reboots. Explicitly issuing the `exportfs -a` command is the reliable solution (for me).

Comment: The explicit, repeated `exportfs -a` didn't change anything for me. Using the full IP address for the one problematic host solved my issue. So while this doesn't explain it and I don't understand it, it was the answer to my problem and what I can recommend to try for others with the same issue.

Comment: Adding an entry for the problematic IP address in /etc/exports resolved my issue as well. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

Check and see if the UID and GUID for the NFS users are the same on server and client. Also, make sure on server the folder is permission 777.
This is my /etc/exports on my server for my client to access.

Create a NFS share directory: (Create each Server with IP, space seperated)

mkdir /var/nfs
vim /etc/exports
        /var/nfs        10.180.82.250(rw,sync,root_squash,anonuid=530,anongid=530,no_subtree_check)

Comment: The UID and GID are not the same. They don't have to be, it works once I got the share mounted on the NFS client. And for the mount operation the user's UIDs should be irrelevant. I do doubt that setting the folder to 777 is a good idea, especially if users can log on to the server. Again, it worked without that once I got it mounted.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, -o vers=3 is the answer:

```
$ sudo mount -o vers=3 192.168.172.1:/A/DIR /mnt
```

- NFS Server: Ubuntu desktop 12.04 32-bit vmware host
- NFS Client: Ubuntu server 12.04 64-bit vmware guest (host-only mode)